# VNC Locking Up After Authentication Failures

Tags: security, vnc, authentication

I have VNC server set up on a Mint machine and need to have 1 or 2 users access a program on the server.  It's all working except that the port is getting NUMEROUS attempts to login to VNC from all over the world, clearly not my 1 or 2 users.   After some number of failed attempts, VNC just shuts down and refuses all access attempts.  I then have to stop and restart the service.  The bogus logins usually cause VNC to lock up within a half hour of restarting.   I don't want to have to manually do this everytime a valid user tries to login and I already put a couple of kill/start instructions in crontab but having crontab doing this every hour seems wrong.  Is there a way to have VNC lockout bogus login attempts without locking everyone out?   Is there a way to whitelist specific IP addresses?

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the VNC server port to something different to prevent most of the bogus logins.

Additionally, use the firewall on the VNC server to whitelist only certain IP from connecting to the VNC ports